# Bottom Sheet Behaviour isn't hidden when I use below code

Tags: android, bottom-sheet

Initially the bottom sheet is remains hidden, when I click on some place then bottom sheet should appear and when I click clear icon then the bottom sheet should be hidden actual manner, which is should be on initial state.

1. Initial App launch code:

```java
bottomSheetInfoBehavior.setHideable(true);
bottomSheetInfoBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN);
```

2. After clicking on some place then this is the code which pops up the bottom sheet:

```java
bottomSheetInfoBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED);
```

3. Finally when the clear icon is clicked then this the code that is hiding the bottom sheet (NOT WORKING):

```java
bottomSheetInfoBehavior.setHideable(true);
bottomSheetInfoBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN);
```

**Expected Result is:**
When the clear icon is clicked then the bottom sheet should not appear in the screen, that should be disabled..! and should not visible in screen..!

Comment: you can use  `dismiss` and `show` method 
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/BottomSheetDialog

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use Bottom sheet's `dismiss` method in clear button.
And 
use `show` method to show the BottomSheet dialog.

> Keep the reference of BottomSheetDialog and use is accordingly.

From the code you have shared u are setting the state/behaviour of the BottomSheet which will be taken care by these method's automatically.

Ref:

- [BottomSheetDialog](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/BottomSheetDialog)